# Will Kezan Mystic always destroy a secret you don't have?

Tags: hearthstone

Kezan Mystic has some specific interactions to avoid breaking some rules of Hearthstone:

1. If both you and your opponent have some of the same secrets in play, Kezan Mystic will always steal a secret you don't already have.
2. If you already have all of the secrets your opponent has, she will destroy a random one of theirs instead of stealing.
3. If you already have five secrets in play, she will destroy a secret instead of stealing.

In the situation in which you have 5 secrets and your opponent has some that you already have and some that you do not have, will Kezan Mystic always destroy one that you don't have (using a combination of rule 1 and rule 3)?

For example, let's say I have secrets [A, B, C, D, E] and my opponent has secrets [A, B, F, G]. When I play Kezan Mystic, am I guaranteed to destroy either F or G? Or is there a chance she will destroy A or B (which I already have)?

[image: Kezan Mystic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this in a duel. I had **ice barrier**, ice block, effigy, mirror entity, vaporize. Science partner had ice block, effigy, mirror entity, vaporize, **counterspell**. I played mystic, vaporize destroyed.

So it looks like it picks one at random to destroy.

Answer (score -1):

This question is very popular. So I came back to edit my existing answer with one that truly answers the question.

This excerpt is taken from [this page](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Kezan_Mystic) and it states:

> Kezan Mystic's Battlecry will attempt to steal an enemy Secret. If the
>   randomly selected Secret is the same as one the controlling player
>   already has active, the Mystic will attempt to pick another.[1](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Kezan_Mystic) If
>   there are no Secrets the player does not already have active, the
>   Mystic will instead destroy a random Secret.

The page goes on to say that if you already have 5, it destroys a secret instead.

**The first part of her battlecry goes off first**, as it's the first part of her battlecry. So she will select one that you don't own. So in your case, you are guaranteed to destroy F or G.

Comment: Your source is just big bold text that says "Source"..

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft WHOOPS forgot to actually add the source in there hahaha i'll fix it now thanks!

Comment: This answer doesn't really touch on the question I had (I was stating the 3 interactions, not questioning them). My question was a bit confusing and I've tried to clarify it after you posted this answer.

Comment: @ken.ganong updated my answer to answer your edit

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your source on this? It's possible that it ignores rule 1 if rule 3 is true.

Comment: To quote the wiki: Kezan Mystic does not allow the player to exceed the 5 secret limit. If her Battlecry would cause the player to have more than 5 secrets, the secret will be destroyed instead of stolen. The wiki can be found here: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Kezan_Mystic

Comment: @ChaseC Neither the video nor the wiki confirm that specifically F or G will be destroyed. They both just confirm rule 3 is true, which we already know to be the case. I highly doubt the rule 1 and rule 3 combination has even been tested.

Comment: @Waterseas What? The mage plays the Mystic with 5 secrets, attempts to steal the Paladin secret that the mage doesn't own, and it's destroyed. That's exactly the question.

Comment: @ChaseC No it's not. The question is: "For example, let's say I have secrets [A, B, C, D, E] and my opponent has secrets [A, B, F, G]. When I play Kezan Mystic, am I guaranteed to destroy either F or G? Or is there a chance she will destroy A or B (which I already have)?" The question you're answer is 'is Rule 3 true?'. The question being asked is 'How do Rule 1 and Rule 3 interact?'.

Comment: The mystic will not steal a secret that you own by default. So rule 1 does not apply here. I thought that was already stated as not being possible in this situation.

Comment: @ChaseC Again, how do you know that is the way the game was programmed? There are two logical ways they programmed it. The first is to start by checking for edge cases, then proceed with the rest of the resolution of the ability. The second is to start progressing with the resolution of the ability, then take care of edge cases when they occur. I personally am a programmer of the first variety, so if I'd created this interaction, it would likely end up having an even chance of destroying any of the secrets, regardless of the kezan's owners secrets. That is unless I caught this or was shown it.

Comment: According to the rules of the card, it checks the owners secrets first and then attempts to steal one it doesn't own. If the owner had 5, it destroys the stolen secret. If the owner has all the secrets the opponent does, it destroys a random enemy secret. That is why I believe my answer is correct.

Comment: @ChaseC I disagree. Again, how do we know it doesn't start by checking the number of secrets you own? I'm of the opinion this question can't be answered accurately until someone actually takes the time to test this.

Comment: Sorry if Im missing something, but I feel I have read most of your answer in the question, itself.

Comment: @timelord that's because the rules of the mystic are in the question. I am simply putting her battlecry in order of which they happen for better clarification of what happens when this situation occurs.